# Adding UIVisualEffectView to tableView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uivisualeffectview

I have added a UIVisualEffectView object form Object Library in Xcode on top of my tableView in the storyBoard. The first cell of the tableView is behind the UIVisualEffectView object . I want to display the first cell of the table view below the blur area. Also when i scroll the table cells it should go behind the blur area .
I tried with this code

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(100, 0, 0, 0)
self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(100, 0, 0, 0)
```

But when i scroll upside the cells won't go behind the blur area .
Help

Also I am trying to change the color of the blur region. Currently its white for light effect and black for dark effect. How do i set a specific color to blur area without effecting its behavior ?

Comment: I posted an answer. Another solution is don't use UITableViewController, use UIViewController instead. Add tableview and blur view as subviews to view controller's root view, blur view is top and above on table view.

Answer (score 1):

Yours cell cant go outside of the table. So you need to extend the tableView, then add contentInset.

Also make sure that your tableView is transparent and visualEffectView is under the tableView.

Comment: Hi.    I am trying to change the color of the blur View to a specific color say red . I did this by changing the background color of the UIVisualEffectView and slightly reducing the alpha value below 1.0 .  But the desired effect of blurring is gone . Is there any other way ?

Comment: well, probably you need to "play" with color brightness.

Comment: I have seen that blur effect fails when the background color is black or any other dark color .

Answer (score 0):

Simple method is make UIVisualEffectView as your table view section header view, for example

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)
    let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    return blurView
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44.0
}
```

it looks like
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped .      Yeah i have used View controller and i added tableview and blur view as separate entities .

Comment: Hi @J.Hunter  . I am also trying to add a blur view at the bottom of the screen(not bottom of the table ) . But when i add a blur view to the main view it hides the whole table view . I want a blur header view type of effect at the bottom of my screen .(not footer of table). Any help ?

Comment: Hello. I would like to inform that i solved the problem i had asked . I added UIVisualEffectView objects at the top and bottom of the screen with setting proper constraints for each of them .

Comment: @Karthik you should set blur view's frame

Comment: @Hunter thanks buddy . Is there any way where we can change the color of the blur View . Right now for dark its black and for light its white . How do we set specific color to the blurView ?